# Nested arrays in GO

Tags: arrays, json, go

I'm trying to map the following JSON to a `map[string]interface{}` in go:

```
{
    "Container": {
        "destinationPath": "/path",
        "volumeMountPath": "/data",
        "token": "token",
        "URL": "https://someurl.com",
        "ids": [{
                "id": "2322",
                "version": "878475"
            },
            {
                "id": "66474",
                "version": "6647"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

so far i have:

```
Data: map[string]interface{}{
    "Container": struct {
        destinationPath string
        volumeMountPath string
        token string
        URL string
        }{"/path", 
          "/data", 
           "someToken",
           "https://someurl.com"},
          },
```

But i'm not sure how to represent the array of ids.

EDIT:
This is what i have so far, the ID's are set but the destinationPath, volumeMountPath and token aren't.

```
Data: map[string]interface{}{
        "Container": struct {
            destinationPath string
            volumeMountPath string
            token string
            URL string
            }{"/path", 
              "/data", 
               "someToken",
               "https://someurl.com"},
              },

            "ids": []map[string]interface{}{
                 map[string]interface{}{
                 `id`:"3q423442",
                 `version`:"325435355",
                },
            },
        },
```

Thanks

Comment: Why not simply pass this through a json parser?

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't passing this into a struct? Like here https://play.golang.org/p/J1LHGtrWVJt

Comment: The fields like `token`  and `destinationPath` won't be set when unmarshalling the JSON data. They need to be exported for that. The `ids` field should be of type `[]ID`, where ID is a struct with an `id` and `version` field. This isn't a nested array, but an array/slice of objects. Also: show what you've tried, it's required to get the help you need.

Comment: Thanks Elias, quite right, i'll update to show what i have. You're also correct about the IDs, using the edit above, they're the only values set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do it:

```
package main
import "fmt"

type (
   a []interface{}
   m map[string]interface{}
)

func main() {
   n := m{
      "Container": m{
         "URL": "https://someurl.com",
         "destinationPath": "/path",
         "token": "token",
         "volumeMountPath": "/data",
         "ids": a{
            m{"id": "2322", "version": "878475"},
            m{"id": "66474", "version": "6647"},
         },
      },
   }
   fmt.Println(n)
}
```